# bootstrap navbar hamburger menu does not work in django app

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4, nav

I  have developed a django app but for some  reason the bootstrap navbar won't show menu items on mobile phone

Whenever I run my app on a mobile device's web browser the hamburger menu does not extend to show  my nav items...it is very odd.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'dashboard:transactions' %}">Transactions</a>
           </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'dashboard:quote' %}">Quote Tool</a>
           </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'dashboard:tracking' %}">My Projects</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'dashboard:home' %}">Home</a>
           </li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'dashboard:support' %}">Support</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
            </li>
            </li>
          </ul>
          {% else %}
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign up</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
            </li>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'dashboard:home' %}">Home</a>
            </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'dashboard:quote' %}">Quote Tool</a>
           </li>
          </ul>
    </div>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine in my Django/Bootstrap-project. You should double check that you have imported the Bootstrap JS correctly, as this is probably the reason why the hamburger won't expand. Try using the starter template https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/ and see if it does the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Patrick, I reloaded afresh js from the boot strap starter template hamburger menu started working on mobile.
Patrick: Ans> "You should double check that you have imported the Bootstrap JS correctly, as this is probably the reason why the hamburger won't expand. Try using the starter template https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/ and see if it does the trick :)"